# How to change datatables row background color

Tags: php, datatables, phalcon

In my Phalcon project, I'm trying to change the color of a row based on some data. I'd appreciate any help. This is what I'm working with. In my controller :

```
private function dataTablesAjax($request)
    {
        
        $params = $columns = $totalRecords = $data = [];
        $params = $_REQUEST;
        $columns = array(
         
            0 => 'payID',
            1 => 'userName',
            2 => 'refundDays',
 
        );
        
        $builder = $this->modelsManager->createBuilder()
            ->columns([
                'payID' => 'a.payID',
                'userName' => 'a.userName',
                'refundDays' => 'a.days',
            ])
            ->addFrom(AccountsRefunds::class, 'ar');
    
        $builder->orderBy($columns[$params['order'][0]['column']] . "   " . $params['order'][0]['dir']);
        $builder->limit($params['length'], $params['start']);

        $result = $builder->getQuery()->execute();

        foreach ($result as $value) {
        
            $nokey = array();
            $nokey[] = $value->payID;
            $nokey[] = $value->userName;
            $nokey[] = $value->refundDays;
            $data[] = $nokey;
        }
        return [
            "draw" => intval($params['draw']),
            "recordsTotal" => intval($totalRecords),
            "recordsFiltered" => intval($totalRecords),
            "data" => $data
        ];
    }
```

Here I just get the data from a query builder and pass the rows in a corresponding view :

```
<div class="card-body">
                <table class="table table-hover responsive" id="dataTables" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>payID</th>
                        <th>userName</th>
                        <th>refundDays</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
</div>
```

The data from datatables gets rendered as a table body. I just want to somehow wrap this part :

```
foreach ($result as $value) {
        
            $nokey = array();
            $nokey[] = $value->payID;
            $nokey[] = $value->userName;
            $nokey[] = $value->refundDays;
            $data[] = $nokey;
}
```

In a table row so that I can dynamically render a class based on some data. I don't know if that's possible though.I'd appreciate any help, thank you !

Comment: _"I just want to somehow wrap this part : [...] In a table row"_ - that phrasing doesn't make much sense; you are only assembling the data there, but the actual table creation, is done by the DataTables script on the client side - so there is nothing you could "wrap" this foreach loop into. Your best bet is probably to handle this via https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowCallback - `row` is the reference to the table row HTML node (so that's what you would set the class on), and `data` is the data for that row.

Comment: @CBroe thanks for the tip appreciate it <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        $('#dataTables').dataTable( {
            "createdRow": function( row, data, dataIndex){
                if( data[2] ==  `someVal`){
                    $(row).addClass('dark-background');
                } elseif(data[2] ==  `someOtherVal`) {
                    $(row).addClass('light-background');
                 }

            }
        });
```

Replace `data[2]` with the specific variabele to check, `someVal` and `someOtherVal` with the value to check for
You can extend this with some more logic, different CSS classes, or even pass things like classnames/colours etc through the data from the API.

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I did. I was just curious, the data that gets rendered from the query is simply just an array with just id's, so like [0=>some value, 1 => some value, 2 => some value], is there any way that It could render the array not with just the ordering of the rows, but the corresponding value names that come from query, for example in my case : [payID => some value, userName => some value] , so that retrieving the data row isn't so hardcoded

Comment: You have to look how `data`  looks like at that location. So do `console.log(data);` in the `createdRow`. I checked in my own code and I have a full object there with key-value pairs, so I could do `data.description` and use that. But i think this depends on how you pass the data to the frontend, it needs to be an object and not an array. See the documentation here: https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowCallback